# Load JSON into coldfusion form

Tags: json, forms, coldfusion

**Question:** Is it possible to load JSON data into the values of my coldfusion form inputs.

**Background:** The JSON data contains the keys which are the names of the inputs and values are the values for the inputs.

*I found a third party script http://code.google.com/p/jquery-load-json/ but I believe it is for HTML forms.*

I can provide examples of the layout of my form and the JSON data if that helps.

This is the script I have so far:

```
<cfinvoke component="RFQ.cfc.data" method="editRFQ" returnvariable="editReturn">
        <cfinvokeargument name="formID" value="#URL.rfqID#">

</cfinvoke> 


<cfset ReBuild = DeserializeJSON(editReturn.data)>



    <script src="scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jquery.loadJSON.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- BELOW IS WHERE I WANT TO USE THE VARIABLE THAT IS RETURNED FROM MY CFINVOKE -->
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            var id = window.location.href.match("(ID=|id=|/)[0-9]+")[0].match("[0-9]+");
        $('form').loadJSON(<cfoutput>#ReBuild#</cfoutput>);
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: What happened when you tried the 3rd party script you mentioned in your question?

Comment: The problem is I can not get the ColdFusion variable "ReBuild" passed to the JQuery script. I can't use cfoutput because I get an error about the data being to complex. I did read something about AJAX and tying ColdFusion and JQuery together using it....

Comment: Is it a requirement to use jQuery 1.6?

Comment: No I can use a new version of JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use the ToScript function to accomplish my task. See updated code below.

```
<cfset ReBuild = DeserializeJSON(editReturn.data)>



    <script src="scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jquery.loadJSON.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

        <cfoutput>
        var #toScript(ReBuild, "jsVar")#;
        </cfoutput>

        $(document).ready(function () {
            var id = window.location.href.match("(ID=|id=|/)[0-9]+")[0].match("[0-9]+");
        $('form').loadJSON(jsVar);
        });

    </script>
```